# CSV Jackson mapper numerical fields into String

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-csv

Is it possible wrap a numeric field from a pojo between  quotes  using CsvMapper from the jackson library?

```
public class Pojo{
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

Using CSVMapper jackson

```
Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
pojo.name= "Peter";
pojo.age= 22;
final CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
csvMapper.configure(CsvGenerator.Feature.ALWAYS_QUOTE_STRINGS, true);
final CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(Pojo.class).withoutHeader().withQuoteChar(CsvSchema.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHAR);
final ObjectWriter ow = csvMapper.writer(schema);
 System.out.println(ow.writeValueAsString(pojo))
```

My expected output will be `"peter","4"` but I'm getting `"peter",4` :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```java
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
```

to the int field of your pojo class :

```java
public class Pojo{
    public String name;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING) 
    public int age;
}
```

It can looks weird since it's a JSON annotation and not CSV, but it's close enough to works

Comment: It is working as expected  thanks for the response I have been marked as correct coz  it is useful,   But  I would like to achieve the result  without  annotation. Using a mapper configuration or something like that. I have a rest api , I want to preserve the  numerical value in json format, but at the moment to persist the data into csv I need all the fields  numerics, boolean.  string, etc. between quotes.

Comment: @AliasCartellano Thanks for the suggestion , however that Feature is only available for  the Json  Writer.  If you have a sample with CSV Writer will be great to see how to configure it.  I found this link related  that feature https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/198